# Посчитать количество писем в Outlook используя C#

Tags: c#, office

Всем привет! Задача такая - необходимо получить количество писем за определенный промежуток времени. К примеру, за прошедший месяц. И все это вывести в таблицу excel. Как вывести в таблицу знаю, но как посчитать и подключиться к почте - не знаю.
Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: outlook тут не причем, думаю, вам надо подключаться к почтовому серверу и смотреть что на нем.

Comment: узнать нужные вам письма может помочь ихнее [api](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations)